# Wagtail 3.x postgres search returns no results

Tags: postgresql, search, resultset, wagtail, wagtail-search

I recently updated from Wagtail 2.13.5 to 3.0.3.  After the update, the `search()` method on Wagtail's `PageQuerySet` returns no results for search terms that clearly *should* return results (and which do when using the older version).

For example, under 2.13, where `search_backend` is an instance of `wagtail.contrib.postgres_search.backend.PostgresSearchBackend`, and `qs` is an instance of `wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet` the following returns lots of results:

```
search_backend.search('popular-search-term', qs, fields=None, operator=None, order_by_relevance=True, partial_match=True)
```

But under 3.0.3, where `search_backend` is now an instance of `wagtail.search.backends.database.postgres.postgres.PostgresSearchBackend` and `qs` is an instance of `wagtail.query.PageQuerySet`, the same call to `search()` will return nothing (an empty queryset).

The data in the `qs` queryset is the same in both cases, so maybe I'm missing something in my configuration of the search backend?  My "settings.py" file has:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
        'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'english',
    },
}
```

and

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.search.backends.database.postgres',
    ...
]
```

I had to guess at the value for 'wagtail.search.backends.database.postgres'. AFAICT, Wagtail's docs don't mention what should go into `INSTALLED_APPS`. But the pre-upgrade value of 'wagtail.contrib.postgres_search' would clearly be wrong, as that module has been removed.

Anyone got an idea why calling `search()` on a `PageQuerySet` would incorrectly return no results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for changing the search backend are documented at https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.15.html#database-search-backends-replaced. In particular:

- You should remove `wagtail.contrib.postgres_search` from INSTALLED_APPS, and do not need to add anything in its place - the existing `wagtail.search` app is sufficient
- After changing over, you need to re-run the `./manage.py update_index` command to ensure that the new search index is populated.

Comment: Thank you - this was great.  I removed "wagtail.search.backends.database.postgres" (I think that's what you meant) from `INSTALLED_APPS`, and ran `./manage.py update_index`.  I just never managed to find those particular release notes. Anyway, the search is working again. Brilliant.